# I get in promise error when i play audio [JS]

Tags: javascript, html

I was trying to play audio on click with Javascript but every time i do that, chrome throws error

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException

I read some articles about it and everyone said that it happens when you are trying
to play it automaticly, without user's action, but my case is different.
Here's my code:

`let correctSoundEffect = new Audio('correct.mp3');
    const checkAnswer = () =>{
    correctSoundEffect.play();
}`

Here's html:
`<button onclick="chechAnswer()">Play</button>`

Comment: You should try looking at this specifically the web audio changes. https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

Answer (score -1):

That error is due to a problem loading the resource.
You probably have a prior error message in your console like

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () correct.mp3:1

or alike, or, your resource couldn't be parsed as a valid audio file.

```js
const src="willfail.mp3";
let correctSoundEffect = new Audio(src);
const checkAnswer = () =>{
    correctSoundEffect.play();
    log.textContent = "check your browser's console";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="checkAnswer()">Play</button>
<pre id="log"></pre>
```

In any case, you may want to check your dev-tools' network panel and know that your code should otherwise work, even though HTML-attribute events are really not good practice...

```js
const src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/1cdwpm3gca9mlo0/kick.mp3";
let correctSoundEffect = new Audio(src);
const checkAnswer = () =>{
    correctSoundEffect.play();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="checkAnswer()">Play</button>
```

A better way of rewriting this:

```js
const src = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/1cdwpm3gca9mlo0/kick.mp3";
let correctSoundEffect = new Audio(src);
document.getElementById('audio_player')
 .addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
   correctSoundEffect.play();
 });
```

```html
<button id="audio_player">Play</button>
```